# Weird behavior of CSS in two Divs

Tags: html, css

I have two div in my HTML web page.First is header at the top with height of 77px.In this div there are dropdown menus also.Now beneath this is my second Div which i want to align center with a width of 960px.Now ,my first div is displaying OK whereas my second Div is displaying 77px down of the first div header whereas i want to show it just beneath the First Div.If i am removing `padding:77px from .center` my second Div is displying at the extreme right of the webpage means after 960px from the center and adding horizontal scrollbar in the webpage.Also the dropdown of the first div is going inside of the second div making it impossible to click as it disappears.

Here is HTML of both div..

```
<div class="header-wrapper">
</div>

 <div id="slideshow-carousel" class="center">               
        <ul id="carousel" class="jcarousel jcarousel-skin-tango">
            <li><a href="#" rel="p1"><img src="img/.jpg" width="960" height="583" alt="#"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" rel="p2"><img src="img/.jpg" width="960" height="583" alt="#"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" rel="p3"><img src="img/.jpg" width="960" height="583" alt="#"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" rel="p4"><img src="img/.jpg" width="960" height="583" alt="#"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" rel="p5"><img src="img/.jpg" width="960" height="583" alt="#"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" rel="p6"><img src="img/.jpg" width="960" height="583" alt="#"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" rel="p7"><img src="img/.jpg" width="960" height="583" alt="#"/></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

And here is the CSS..

```
.header-wrapper {
background: url("../img/.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
z-index: 60001;     
width: 100%;
height: 77px;
margin: 0 auto; 
}

 .center
{
padding-top: 77px;
margin: 0 auto;
width:70%; 
}
body {
font-family:arial;  
}

 img {
 border:0;
}

#slideshow-carousel {

width:960px;
position:relative
}

#slideshow-carousel ul {
margin:0; 
padding:0;
list-style:none;
}

#slideshow-carousel li {
background:#fff; 
height:583px; 
position:relative
}

#slideshow-carousel li .arrow {
left:3px; 
top:28px; 
position:absolute; 
width:20px; 
height:40px; 
background:url(images/arrow_white.png) no-repeat 0 0; 
display:block;
}

#slideshow-carousel li a {
background:#000; 
display:block; 
width:960px; 
height:583px;
}


#slideshow-carousel .active {
filter:alpha(opacity=100); 
-moz-opacity:1.0; 
-khtml-opacity: 1.0; 
opacity: 1.0;
}

#slideshow-carousel .faded {
filter:alpha(opacity=50); 
-moz-opacity:0.5; 
-khtml-opacity: 0.5; 
opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Here is the sample fiddle demo..[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J2uk5/)

Please help me ..I am sorry for adding it without image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this, I've removed the `padding-top`, `margin: 0 auto;` on .header-wrapper. I've also added `clear: both;` to prevent this div from having elements align to its left or right.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/J2uk5/2/).

Comment: If i remove padding-top: 77px from .center my second div is going to the extreme right and adding horizontal scroll bar in the web page.Also the dropdown menu of the first Div is not click able agian

Comment: Update your JS fiddle with the code to the menu and we'll take a second look.

Comment: Sir my web page contains images ,so its hard to make jsfiddle ,Please tell me why is the gap between the first and second Div

Comment: It's hard to resolve the problem if I can't see the full picture. Maybe post a link to your website, over a screen. :)

Answer (score 0):

Take the margin:0 auto; out of the .header-wrapper (the width of the element is 100% of the body, no need to center it), then you can remove the padding-top from .center.

```
.header-wrapper {
    background: url("../img/.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    z-index: 60001;     
    width: 100%;
    height: 77px;
}

.center
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:70%; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/J2uk5/1/

Comment: Your jsfiddle didn't represent all of the elements that you have in play.  Try to reproduce the problem in jsfiddle so it represents what you are seeing locally.

Comment: Sir my web page contains images ,so its hard to make jsfiddle ,Please tell me why is the gap between the first and second Div